# Linear basis of the geometric algebra $\mathcal{G}_{2}$

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, multilinear-algebra

My question is about the last part of the proof (in bold), for more context, I'll quote all the proof:

> (Linear basis of $\mathcal{G}_{2}$ ) The elements $\langle 1, e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{1} e_{2} \rangle
> \in \mathcal{G}_{2}$ are linearly independent. In particular,
> $\operatorname{dim} \mathcal{G}_{2}=4 .$ Moreover, the linear subspaces
> $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{0}=\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{R}$
> $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{1}=\left\langle e_{1}, e_{2}\right\rangle=E_{2},$ and
> $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{2}=\left\langle e_{1} e_{2}\right\rangle$ are independent of
> the orthonormal basis used to construct them.

> *Proof* Assume a linear
> relation of the form $$ \lambda+\lambda_{1} e_{1}+\lambda_{2}
>  e_{2}+\lambda_{12} e_{1} e_{2}=0 $$ Multiplying by $e_{1}$ from the
> left and from the right, we get the relation $$ \lambda+\lambda_{1}
>  e_{1}-\lambda_{2} e_{2}-\lambda_{12} e_{1} e_{2}=0 $$ Adding the last
> two relations, we conclude that $\lambda+\lambda_{1} e_{1}=0$ and
> hence $\lambda=\lambda_{1}=0 .$ So we are left with the relation
> $\lambda_{2} e_{2}+\lambda_{12} e_{1} e_{2}=0$ or, multiplying on the
> right by $e_{2}, \lambda_{2}+\lambda_{12} e_{1}=0,$ which gives
> $\lambda_{2}=\lambda_{12}=0$ Since the assertions on
> $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{0}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{1}=E_{2}$ are
> clear, what remains is to see that $\mathcal{G}_{2}^{2}$ is
> independent of the basis. We will do this by giving a description of
> it that is basis independent.
>
> Consider the map $E_{2}^{2} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_{2}$ given by $(v, w)
>  \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v w-w v)$. **Since this map is bilinear and
> skew-symmetric, it gives a linear map** $\wedge^{2} E_{2} \rightarrow
>  G_{2}$ **(which is basis independent by definition) such that** $v \wedge w
> \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v w-w v)$. **In particular,** $$ e_{1} \wedge e_{2}
>  \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(e_{1} e_{2}-e_{2} e_{1}\right)=e_{1} e_{2} $$
> **which shows that the map in question yields a canonical linear**
> **isomorphism** $$ \wedge^{2} E_{2} \simeq G_{2}^{2} $$ **Thus we actually**
> **have a canonical linear isomorphism** $$ \wedge E_{2}=\wedge^{0} E_{2}
>  \oplus \wedge^{1} E_{2} \oplus \wedge^{2} E_{2} \simeq
> \mathcal{G}_{2}^{0}+\mathcal{G}_{2}^{1}+\mathcal{G}_{2}^{2}=\mathcal{G}_{2} $$

My question is pretty basic but I think I am missing something here :
How does being skew-symmetric and bilinear gives a linear map $\wedge^{2} E_{2} \rightarrow
\mathcal{G}_{2}$  ? if I understood correctly: if I have a bilinear and skew-symmeteric map that takes an element from $E_2$ (2-vector) to $\mathcal{G}_{2}$ then I have a linear map from $\wedge^{2} E_{2} $ to $\mathcal{G}_{2}$.
To see this, I've just applied this to a simple exapmle to see

($v \wedge w + z \wedge y) \mapsto 1/2 (vw-wv) + 1/2(zy - yz) = 1/2 ((vw + zy)-(wv + yz)) $

I am assuming that if I take two elements, by linearity I should find something like $(v+z) \wedge (w+y)$, I am probably applying incorrectly, but what's linear with respect to what in the explanation of this proof?

and how does the map in question yields a canonical linear isomorphism?

Thank you.

Comment: Can [this document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.07159.pdf) be of some help ?